# warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch?

Tags: c++, if-statement, comparison, warnings

This code throws a warning when I compile it under VS.

```
if (m_nDarksideEffectAttCnt < m_DarkTargetIndex.size())

if (m_DuelWatchUserList.size() <= iIndex)
```

Warning:

```
& warning C4018: '<=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 6):

As the warning says, this is because of the comparison because of the signed  (i.e. `m_nDarksideEffectAttCnt`, `iIndex`) and unsigned(i.e `m_DuelWatchUserList.size()`) types.

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) exactly for this, we have [`std::cmp_less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp)

```
#include <utility> // std::cmp_less

if (std::cmp_less(m_nDarksideEffectAttCnt, vec.size()))
{
    // 
}
```

This also covers the case, if we mistakenly `static_cast` the `-1` (i.e. `int`)to `unsigned int`. That is, the following will not give you an error:

```
static_assert(1u < -1);
```

But the following will

```
static_assert(std::cmp_less(1u, -1)); // error
```

---

Also check out the other functions

```
std::cmp_equal
std::cmp_not_equal
std::cmp_greater
std::cmp_less_equal
std::cmp_greater_equal
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about those functions! +1

Answer (score 2):

`m_nDarksideEffectAttCnt` and `iIndex` are of *signed* types, while (the standard library) `size()` functions returns an *unsigned* type (`std::size_t`).

You can get rid of the warning by changing types of `m_nDarksideEffectAttCnt` and `iIndex` to `std::size_t` or by casting in the comparisons:

```
if(static_cast<std::size_t>(m_nDarksideEffectAttCnt) < m_DarkTargetIndex.size())
//...
if (m_DuelWatchUserList.size() <= static_cast<std::size_t>(iIndex))
```

or if `iIndex` and `m_nDarksideEffectAttCnt` can have negative values:

```
if(m_nDarksideEffectAttCnt < static_cast<long long>(m_DarkTargetIndex.size())
//...
if (static_cast<long long>(m_DuelWatchUserList.size()) <= iIndex)
```